# Why does a for loop not require a mutable iterator?

Tags: rust

If I want to consume an iterator by hand, it has to be mutable:

```
let test = vec![1, 2, 3];
let mut test_mut = test.iter();
while let Some(val) = test_mut.next() {
    println!("{:?}", val);
}
```

But I can happily consume it with a `for` loop, even if it's immutable.

```
let test = vec![1, 2, 3];
let test_imm = test.iter();
for val in test_imm {
    println!("{:?}", val);
}
```

I *think* this works because `test_imm` is moved into the for loop's block, so `test_imm` can't be used by the outer block any more and is (from the point of view of the outer block) immutable up until the for loop, and then it's inaccessible, so it's okay.

Is that right? Is there more to be explained?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's exactly right. Since it's moved to the for loop, the for loop now owns it and can do whatever it wants with it, including "making it" mutable. Consider this analogous example, where we appear to be mutating `xs` despite it being immutable, but really it's because we're moving it, so the new owner is free to do with it whatever it wants, including re-binding it as mutable:

```
let xs: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3];

fn append(v: Vec<i32>, x: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut my_v = v;
    my_v.push(x);
    my_v
}

let appended = append(xs, 4);
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=045ba44ab0a9fce81441&version=stable)

Note that the function can be made shorter using the `mut` parameter convenience syntax:

```
fn append(mut v: Vec<i32>, x: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    v.push(x);
    v
}
```

This is more or less explained [in the `iter` module's documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/#for-loops-and-intoiterator).